# CSS gradients vs background Image?

Tags: html, css

Some years ago, I've seen a lot of CSS codes using `background-image: url(xxx.png)` simulating a gradient background filter,
since only (please, correct if I'm wrong here) IE proprietary filter would provide CSS gradient.

Nowadays - keeping in mind the most used browsers today and portable devices browsers (smartphones/tablets), should I use:

- CSS gradients, with 1 background property for each engine

OR

- background-image: url(xxx.png), 1 tiny image (but still a browser request);

**?**

And how about IE9 issue there I have seen in some CSS gradient generators (ie collorzilla)?

UPDATE: sorry I wasn't very clear.. my question is **not "how** to do that", is about wich is **more efficient**, **acceptable** or the **correct way**. thanks!

Comment: You could also provide the gradient image in the CSS itself (DataURL), which removes the additional browser request.

Comment: @Zeta but I think that in this case, I lose maintainability, in my opinion.. :)

Comment: @Zeta you'll remove the extra request but introduce 33% overhead to size. Only small images benefits from being included as data-uris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very sensitive issue. In the company where I work, we did some research based on our customers and the views of their sites. The conclusion was: there are many users of IE8.

There are several ways to make the gradient CSS work in IE, one of the best I know is css3 pie: [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/)

However, an image format fillet, with a pixel width or height weighs almost inconsiderable, the only concern is that it generates a requisition more.

So my opinion in my case was to use the css3pie ... it will probably work on smartphones as well.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: +1. CSS3Pie is the best option for supporting gradients in old IE versions: It has fewer bugs than `filter` gradients; it means you can write standard CSS even for old IE; and it avoids having to write messy edge cases specifically for IE9.

Answer (score 1):

So I had this same question myself, hoping to find the best solution with regards to performance, and I had come to the following conclusions:

Pro Gradient:

- Images can take up bandwidth, so when first fetching the image it may take longer. That being said, it is important to remember that the browser caches these files, and with properly formatted images this becomes less of an issue still. The biggest impact would likely be on casual users logging in for the first time in remote areas where internet reception is questionable.
- Gradient elements are more flexible. Images may depend on having hard coded dimensions to display properly in the element they define, whereas gradients can adapt to the environment a little better.
- In the spirit of flexibility, you can also consider that it isn't just the dimensions that can be modified, you'll have more control of the background itself when setting it on the fly through javascript.

Pro Image:

- Gradients are harder for the browser to display. Rather than showing an image already made, you are asking the browser to construct the image itself. This may be an issue on older or less capable devices, as they may not run as quickly or as well as you may like.
- Images can allow for more complex patterns, (eg: you want a gradient around a triangular shape). Depending on what you're going for, a gradient may be **able** to do it, but the CSS could get complicated very quickly.

Those are the factors that I could come up with, hopefully I didn't leave anything big out. As for the direction I went, I tend to end up using gradients, for the aforementioned flexibility. Bandwidth was also somewhat of a concern, as I regularly have users in these remote areas with shotty reception.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what HTML5 Boilerplate does:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>   <html class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>   <html class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>  <html class="lt-ie10"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class=""><!--<![endif]-->
```

Now you have a `<html>` with classes for IE:

IE6 --> lt-ie10, lt-ie9, lt-ie8, lt-ie7

IE7 --> lt-ie10, lt-ie9, lt-ie8,

IE8 --> lt-ie10, lt-ie9

IE9 --> lt-ie10

And in your CSS:

```
.element { background-image: /*Your CSS3 gradient declaration */; }
.lt-ie10 { background-image: url(/*Your PNG file*/); }
```